# Codeception is not rolling back DB changes in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am new to codeception and I am using it to test a web service I am creating in laravel 5. So my main config file looks like so:

**codeception.yml**

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carparts'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'SomePassword'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

And the suite file called **api.suite.yml** looks like so:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: PhpBrowser
    config:
        Laravel5:
            cleanup: true
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

I also copy pasted the whole dump of my database `carparts` into the `dump.sql` file but still when I run the tests, I still see new users created which are being created in the tests. What am I missing? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you use Innodb engine? Show your CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: I am looking at the DB in PhpMyAdmin and all the tables are Inndodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did not know that in order to rollback the DB I need to enable the Db module:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - Db
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: PhpBrowser
    config:
        Laravel5:
            cleanup: true
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

And that did it.